# Getting Wrong Answer in linked list palindrome

Tags: c++, stack

I have written a code in c++ to check whether the linked list is palindrome on not. The code is given below.

Every time  I am running the program i am getting the value returned as 1 . In the given example i am using non palindrome string then also i am getting the same answer that its a palindrome.

I have used the c++ standard template library to execute this code

```
#include<iostream>
    #include<stack>
    using namespace std;

    struct node{
        char data;
        node *next;
    };



    void push(struct node** head,char data)
    {
        struct node *newnode= new node;
        newnode->data=data;
        newnode->next=(*head);
        (*head)=newnode;
    }

    void print(struct node *ptr)
    {
        while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<"  " <<ptr->data;
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    }

    //this is the function to check palindrome
    int checkpalindrome(node *head)
    {
        stack<char>s;
        node *current=head;
        while(current!=NULL)
        {
            s.push(current->data);
            current=current->next;  
        }


        while(current!=NULL && !s.empty() )
        {
                int ele=s.top();
                s.pop();
                if(ele==current->data)
                current=current->next;
                else
                {
                    return 0;
                    break;
                }

        }
    }


    int main(){

    node *first=NULL;
        push(&first,'a');
        push(&first,'b');
        push(&first,'b');
        push(&first,'d');
        int c=checkpalindrome(first);
        if(c==0){cout<<"not a palindrome";
        }
        else
        {cout<<"its a palindrome";
        }

    }
```

There is no syntax error  . Please tell me the logic error in my code

Comment: Friend, i think you have got solution, but as programming experience few things I would like to add. Your code, had created linked list but when you try to trace elements, the list stores element in reverse order of store, it actually acts like stack. If you print your pointer first it will print dbba, while you stored addb. Also the check palindrome function you havent put return value if its palindrome, and its wrong practice. I would recommend you to add return value if it satisfies condition to say value 1. This will be consistent all time your list is palindrome. Lastly in same function y

Comment: Random observation: why are you `#include<stack>` but instead of using it implementing you're own? (Completely rhetorical)

Comment: @Assimilater maybe he was planning on using it but changed his mind, I dunno ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Assimilater i will try with own implementation also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `current` to point to the head, the 2nd while loop never executes in the palindrome function because it is NULL at that point.

```
// ...

*current = head; // RESET current

while(current!=NULL && !s.empty())
{
    // ...
}

// ...
```